# How to pass in a count to dynamic json object

Tags: javascript, karate

Im very new to javascript. Im trying to make a way of counting from 0-5, and placing those numbers in a pair and then calling a function to click on boxes correlating to their index value. here is what i have so far:

```
* table deviceValsTable
     | boxLocator    | indexList |
     | brandCheckbox |   [0,1]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [0,2]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [0,3]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [0,4]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [0,5]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [1,2]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [1,3]   |
     | brandCheckbox |   [ect..]   |
 * def indexList = karate.get('indexList')
    * def locator = karate.get('boxLocator')
    * def boxes = locateAll(locator)
    * def clickBox = function(index){ boxes.get(index).click()}
    * karate.map(indexList, clickBox)
```

I need to do this 16 times

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use a `Scenario Outline`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests

```
Scenario Outline:
* print indexList

Examples:
| indexList! |
| [0, 1]     |
| [2, 0]     |
```

Note that `Scenario Outline`-s can take a dynamic data-source: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

Also see loops: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

Comment: Hey Peter, Thanks so much for the reply. I dont think im asking my question correctly. Like i said i'm very new to this language. Im trying to do something like this;
  for (i=1; i<6; i++) and create an object pass to the function instead of making a table.

Comment: Thank you for your time Peter, Ill continue reading the documentation.